# Adding next and previous buttons to a ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I was converting the following below ui to code.

[image]

I didn't find a suitable package for it, im stepper also didn't have the ability to customize in this way.
So I tried to use listView.builder.
Now I don't know how to add the next and previous buttons.
so that the number inside the scroll view scrolls like the picture below and is placed in the view area.

[image]

If you know a suitable package, introduce it.
my code:

```
FadingEdgeScrollView.fromScrollView(
                        gradientFractionOnEnd: 0.2,
                        gradientFractionOnStart: 0.15,
                      
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          controller: _controller2,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                            int one = index + 1;
                            int two = 0;

                            Color colorWhat(int q) {
                              Color color;
                              if (q == two) {
                                color = Color(0xff0AFF6C);
                              } else {
                                color = Colors.white;
                              }
                              return color;
                            }

                            double sizeOfCircle(int qq) {
                              int size;
                              if (qq == 0) {
                                size = 27;
                              } else {
                                size = 22;
                              }
                              return size.toDouble();
                            }

                            double sizeOfCircleText(int qqq) {
                              double size;
                              if (qqq < 10) {
                                size = 13.9;
                              } else {
                                size = 13.7;
                              }
                              return size;
                            }
                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    width: sizeOfCircle(index),
                                    // height: sizeOfCircle(index),
                                    // padding: EdgeInsets.all(sizeOfCircle(index)),
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        2, 0, 17, 0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: colorWhat(index),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      boxShadow: const [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          offset: Offset(0, 5),
                                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                                          spreadRadius: -7,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      one.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: sizeOfCircleText(index),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              onTap: () =>
                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                SnackBar(
                                  content: Text((index+1).toString()),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: you can also make the Stepper horizontal and vertical.

Comment: what customization do you want?

Comment: Does it have to be a ListView or ok with other widget stepper

Comment: @MunsifAli Including the shadow behind each number and the back line.
I haven't tested the back and front buttons either, I don't know if they can be colored or shaded.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The stepper didn't have the required capacity, or at least I couldn't, so I went to the list view. If you know a more suitable option, tell me

Comment: @MunsifAli Also, the fade mode from around, for which I used FadingEdgeScrollView

Answer (score 1):

first select a current index like this:

```dart
int currentPageIndex = 0;
```

and then on tap function. Write a code like this

1. for decrement...

   ```
   if (currentPageIndex == 4) {
     return;
   }
   setState(() {
     currentPageIndex += 1;
   });
   ```
2. for Increment...

   ```
   if (currentPageIndex == 4) {
     return;
   }
   setState(() {
     currentPageIndex += 1;
   });
   ```

Change your text...

```
Text(
  '${index + 1}'
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    fontSize: sizeOfCircleText(index),
  ),
),
```

and change your onTap function like this:

```
   onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              currentPageIndex = index;
            });
          },
```